# Permission handler Alert dialog barrierdismissible set false

Tags: flutter, permissions, android-permissions

Why permission dialog can be dismissed by tapping outside dialog and doing so will result in the permission being permanently denied. How can set barrierdismissible false alert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `barrierDismissible` to `false` in `showDialog`

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _dialogBuilder(context);
            },
            child: Text('show dialog'))
      ]),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> _dialogBuilder(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog<void>(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('dialog'),
        content: const Text('accept or reject'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('accept'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('reject'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: my need permission handler alert dialog barrierDismissible.

Comment: Yes. only the permission message alert dialog.

Comment: the permission won't be denied, you have to either click on accept or reject, you won't be able to dismiss the dialog by clicking outsite the box

Comment: But android 12, permission alert dialog dismiss when tap out side and it return Permission.permanentlyDenied.

Comment: have you set `barrierDismissible` to false?

Comment: But permission handler alert dialog show on system

Comment: can you add your code in your question, i may be able to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252464/discussion-between-hossain72-and-saad).